# How to open up the Battery usage Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have been looking around for a way to launch the Battery use (Setting-->Battery&performance-->Power usage) activity through my android app, but cannot find it.I want know how to start this Activity though an Action or Intent.

What is the action that I should pass into an Intent in order to get the Battery use(which show every apps usage of battery) screen to open up ?

I try to read the guide which Google provide, but I failed.

Intent intent =  new Intent(?????);
                startActivity(intent);

I only want to start this Activity.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY);
startActivity(intent );
```

Comment: Ok，It work，thanks very much！

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new 
IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```